# Match Rows in Two DataFrames using Latitude & Longitude Data To 4 Decimal Places

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames, each containing customer account information (e.g. name, address, sales, latitude and longitude). Both DataFrames have the latitude and longitude of the account. I'd like to match the accounts in the two DataFrames based on the latitude and longitudes by making the assumption that if the latitude and longitude both math at 4 decimal places then the accounts must also match. The output would be a new series (e.g. "Matched") in one of the two DataFrames that is "1" if there is a match or "0" if there isn't a match.

How can I do this using Pandas?

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthesize a string column of "lat, lng" formatted to your favorite decimal precision.

Then just `.merge( ... )` your dataframes on that.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: How do you merge on two columns? Create a third column by converting the lat / long toa string and combining into one column — maybe that's work but it's a bit clumsy?

Comment: The problem setup implicitly suggests that one or more dataframes have lat / longs of 5 digits precision or more. The point of synthesizing a new field isn't really to combine two columns. Rather, it is to allow reduced precision comparison via the nice simple equality operator, without fiddling around with expressions like `abs(lat1 - lat2) < thresh`.   You also have `np.format_float_positional(lat1, precision=4)` at your disposal, if you like.  https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: Thanks @J_H — you're right — you can merge on two keys by passing a list to the "on" parameter. This solved the issue.